# how to download today's files based on filename using sftp in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

In my "Remote_InputFolder" directory i had the below list of files.

```
physicalDevice_20130722000000_incremental.xml
userProfile_20130722000000_full.xml
physicalDevice_20130723000000_incremental.xml
userProfile_20130723000000_full.xml
physicalDevice_20130724000000_incremental.xml
userProfile_20130724000000_full.xml
```

i want to download files having today's date in their filename. i used the below sftp code, but it's not working.

```
sftp ${SFTPUserName}@${SFTPHostName} <<EOF .... get *{date +%Y%m%d}*.xml ..EOF
```

Any help please.

Comment: It should be `$(date +%Y%m%d)` instead of `{date +%Y%m%d}`

Comment: Its not working. i tried giving "get *\${date +%Y%m%d}*.xml" in the code.

I got the below exception

sftp>   get *${date +%Y%m%d}*.xml
File "/root/anil/SFTP_test/*${date" not found.
sftp>   exit

Comment: Note I suggested `(` (parenthesis) instead of `{` (curly brackets).

Comment: am Sorry. It's working fine now.Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should be:

```
$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

> instead of:

```
{date +%Y%m%d}
```